# Set Focusable=False cause TabItem not selectable in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

In a window I have some TextBoxes and a TabControl and I want only textboxes be selectable.
I set `Focusable=False` in `TabItem`. But this made TabItem not selectable. How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your description is that you want to change focus using "Tab" key and you don't want TabControl to be selected.

For that instead of setting Focusable=false, set IsTabStop="False".

```
<TabItem IsTabStop="False" Header="Item 1">Content1</TabItem>
```

Setting IsTabStop="False" will ignore that control while changing focus using Tab key.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: in this case if I click on tab, focus remains on TabItem.

Comment: You can  change IsTabStop properties value programatically when it recieves control. Please give more details about the question.